# How to remove a DataFrame from a list of DataFrame's?

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of dfs:

```
>>> print(li)
[             A          B         C
name1  2020-06-30  2020-12-28  2020-06-01

             A          B           C          B           C
name2  2020-06-23  2020-11-18  2020-09-24  2020-05-27  2021-01-05

             A          B           C          D          
name3  2021-01-22  2020-07-14  2020-11-25  2020-06-15 ]
```

In order to be able to concatenate each element, I'd like to remove the second element ：`li.remove(li[1])`

This gives `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Can anyone possibly help me with this?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pop` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
#remove inplace second element
li.pop(1)
#join together
df = pd.concat(li)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple case of straight **python** remove the dataframe from the list before you use `pd.concat()`

```
li = [pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("12-Mar-2021", periods=len(cols)).values.reshape(1,len(cols)), 
                   columns=cols) for i in range(3) for cols in [list("ABCD")[0:random.randint(2,4)]]]

del li[1]
pd.concat(li)
```

#### output

```
           A          B          C          D
0 2021-03-12 2021-03-13 2021-03-14 2021-03-15
0 2021-03-12 2021-03-13        NaT        NaT
```